# Parallel.Invoke wait if tasks are busy

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Can someone help me with the following code please. in the line:

```
Parallel.Invoke(parallelOptions, () => dosomething(message));
```

I want to invoke up to 5 parallel tasks (if there are 5 busy, wait for the next available, then start it... if only 4 busy, start a 5th, etc)

```
    private AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent1 = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 };

    private void threadProc()
    {
        queue.ReceiveCompleted += MyReceiveCompleted1;
        Debug.WriteLine("about to start loop");
        while (!shutdown)
        {
            queue.BeginReceive();
            autoResetEvent1.WaitOne();
        }
        queue.ReceiveCompleted -= MyReceiveCompleted1;
        queue.Dispose();
        Debug.WriteLine("we are done");
    }

    private void MyReceiveCompleted1(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = queue.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);
        Debug.WriteLine("number of max tasks: " + parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism);
        Parallel.Invoke(parallelOptions, () => dosomething(message));
        autoResetEvent1.Set();
    }

    private void dosomething(Message message)
    {
        //dummy body
        var i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            i++;
            if (i == 5 || i == 10 || i == 15) Debug.WriteLine("loop number: " + i + " on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            if (i == 15)
                break;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("finished task");
    }
```

THE RESULTS I GET NOW:

1) with dosomething() as you see it above, i get only one at a time (it waits)

2) with dosomething() changed to below, i get none stops x number of tasks (not limited or obeying MaxDegreeOfParallelism

```
    private async Task dosomething(Message message)
    {
        //dummy body
        var i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            i++;
            if (i == 5 || i == 10 || i == 15) Debug.WriteLine("loop number: " + i + " on thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            if (i == 15)
                break;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("finished task");
    }
```

What am i doing wrong to get what i want accomplished?

THE OUTCOME I WANT:

in "MyReceiveCompleted", i want to make sure only 5 simultaneous tasks are processing messages, if there are 5 busy ones, wait for one to become available.

Comment: you need to take a look at `TaskScheduler`. Write your custom Scheduler to execute only 5 tasks at a time.

Comment: You provide only single `Action` to `Parallel.Invoke`, so no parallel execution possible. You better look to [System.Threading.Task.Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
Parallel.Invoke(parallelOptions, () => dosomething(message));
```

is telling the TPL to start a new parallel operation with *only one thing to do*. So, the "max parallelism" option of 5 is kind of meaningless, since there will only be one thing to do. `autoResetEvent1` ensures that there will only be one parallel operation at a time, and each parallel operation only has one thing to do, so the observed behavior of only one thing running at a time is entirely expected.

When you change the delegate to be asynchronous, what is actually happening is that the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is only applied to the *synchronous* portion of the method. So once it hits its first `await`, it "leaves" the parallel operation and is no longer constrained by it.

The core problem is that `Parallel` works best when the number of operations is known ahead of time - which your code doesn't know; it's just reading them from a queue and processing them as they arrive. As someone commented, you *could* solve this using dynamic task parallelism with a `TaskScheduler` that limits concurrency.

However, the simplest solution is probably TPL Dataflow. You can create an `ActionBlock<T>` with the appropriate throttling option and send messages to it as they arrive:

```
private ActionBlock<string> block = new ActionBlock<string>(
    message => dosomething(message),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 });

private void MyReceiveCompleted1(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  var message = queue.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);
  block.Post(message);
  autoResetEvent1.Set();
}
```

One nice aspect of TPL Dataflow is that it also understands asynchronous methods, and will interpret `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` as a maximum degree of concurrency.

Comment: Thanks! this simple ActionBlock is what i was looking for!!